# How to create .tcn format file by Python?

Tags: file, python-3.x, format

I need to create a .tcn format file. I need to put some integer, binary and hexadecimal values and then import the .tcn format file to an application and the application will be able to read the values stored in it. The application is already configured to have the ability to read from a .tcn format file. But I need to make the .tcn format file using Python. I know how to create a .txt format file using Python, but I do not know how to create a .tcn format file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: i have not written any code since i do not even know how to create/open a .tcn format file with Python, or whether it is even possible to create/open a  .tcn format file by Python and write on it

Comment: @rrra, can you please update your question/post with what application is reading the file, what have you researched so far, where is the file definition, and what the purpose of the file is. Including some code you have tried so far.